# Convection/conduction simulation run from equal temp, but losing heat

Tags: simulations, thermal-conductivity, convection

I was investigating the effects of heated wall materials on outdoor air temperature and indoor air temperature with a certain software. The system is as the following:

- 1x1x1 meter cube of outdoor air
- 1x1x0.15 meter cube of brick wall
- 1x1x1 meter cube of indoor air

The radiation source was set on the outdoor side of the wall. I set the heating time to 4 hours. Shortly after the heating began, the inner half part of the brick wall started to lose heat (by around 1 degC) and consequently causes the indoor air temperature to drop by 1 degC. The outer half part of the brick wall absorbs heat and starts to increase its temperature, but not yet reaching the inner half of the brick wall. After more than an hour, the heat has reached the entirety of the brick wall and finally causes the indoor air temperature to rise due to convection. I set all initial temperature to 293.15 Kelvin (solid and fluid initial temperature), so theoretically, in a process that only involves heating, there shouldn't be a region with a lower temperature than that.

My question: what causes the drop of temperature in the middle part of the brick wall? In a closed system, shouldn't the temperature remain the same until heat finally reaches that section?

I haven't been able to retrieve the data but I notice this from the visual aid given by the software, and I lower the color legend range to only 5 degC from min to max so I can notice the subtlest change in temperature. Please help me, any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't have the source code of the software it is not possible to know where the mistake is generated. Or you have it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I should probably rephrase the question to whether the simulation results were physically accurate phenomenon or was it just basic source code error.